# Deployed Android project using Flash Builder Burrito not working on mobiles

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, builder

I have created a simple "Hello World" Application using Flash Builder Burrito SDK. I have tested the result in the emulator it is working great.

After that i deployed the application using "Export Release Build Option" and entered valid certificate details and created the .apk file. I copied the .apk file into the device and i run the application. Iam unable to run the app. I have tried these in 3 android supported devices and in each of these i am getting different error messages.
I have mentioned the device in which i have tested and the error message i got while i tried to install the app (.apk  file)

1. HTC Desire - "Error while parsing the package of the application"
2. Samsung Galaxy Tab - "Error while parsing the package of the application"
3. LG Optimus one (LG P500) - "Application not installed"

I have created a *New Mobile Project* in the flash SDK and added simple label "HELLO WORLD" in the view section.

Before deploying i have installed Adobe AIR 2.5 in the device.

Whether iam missing any of the steps to deploy correctly in the device. If so, please let me know. Also i need to know whether any restrictions are there for applications developed using *Flash Burrito Preview Release*. (whether by default all android mobile version more than 2.1 will support it?)

Also when i try to install "Tour De Mobile Flex" apk in LG Optimus, it is saying "Device not supported" message.

How do i overcome these problems to run the apk file without any problems.

If you need any other detail please let me know, i will explain it in detail.

Thanks in Advance,
Srinivasan.C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flash builder go to 'window' menu - 'Preferences' and in preference window go to 'Target Platforms' - 'Google Android' and set Adnroid SDK Location.
now you can able to run the applciation

Thanks 
Thulasiram